# Listing all the users part of an AD group

Tags: macos, command-line, active-directory

I want to know the users part of an existing Active Directory Group.

Trying to use the id utility : https://ss64.com/osx/id.html

Seems like i can get the list of groups that a user is part of with the command:-

```
id -Gn username
```

Not sure if there is way to get list of users part of an existing group.

Comment: So you need a command line utility for Microsoft Active Directory on macOS? And you can't use a PC or a Windows VM?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to be about Apple products or their use.